# multi-tier carousel on one webpage

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this carousel script multiple times on the same page. [sample](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/03/carousel-3d-jquery-plugin-3d-carousel-slider/)

I am trying to stack multiple versions of each carousel on top of each other and allow independent turning of each carousel.

I understand a little of jquery and PHP but im just not sure how to proceed with the coding of adding a 2nd, 3rd and 4th carousel to the webpage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try freelancer.com they can help you

Comment: I understand a good deal of this but I now have figured out that I just need to attach IDS to the items...thanks for the help.